# RegEX checking for X.X, Empty Line and the word Employees in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hey all I am looking for a way using **REGEX** to detect if the string its looking at has a X.X in it or not.

Examples of some strings would be:

```
1.0- Back of Place
1.1- Drive-thru
Bob Barker
Employees

2.1- Closing                            
Garret Neal
3.0 - Day
3.1 -Day/Night
Bill Gates
4.1- Training
[etc etc etc]
```

I am just interested if the string has either **X.X** or **Employees**. Once I can detect those 2 things the list should then look like this:

```
Bob Barker              
Garret Neal
Bill Gates
[etc etc etc]
```

I've tried **[0-9]{1,3}** but it doesn't seem to give me what I want:

```
Dim blah = Regex.Match("1.1- Drive-thru", "[0-9]{1,3}", RegexOptions.Singleline).ToString()

MsgBox(blah)
```

Comment: You mean find a string that starts with `digits.digits`? Use `(?m)^\d+\.\d+.*`. See [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/yB1yV8/1)

Comment: Based on what @WiktorStribixew said, I also included the "Employees" entry in the list. `(?:^\d+\.\d+.*|Employees)`

Comment: I do not understand this question: 1) input data (a string, a list/array?) 2) final result (a multiline string, an array?). The sample code is rather misleading. If it is a multiline string, I'd rather use [`(?m)^(?:Employees.*|\d+\.\d+.*)\r?\n?`](https://regex101.com/r/yV5zF7/1) regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the OP is trying to EXCLUDE everything starting with X.X and/or Employee.

Comment: @Jeroen: I find the word *EXCLUDE* a very generic word (in the context of a regex) that always needs clarification.

Comment: If `Regex.Replace(str, "(?m)^(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+).*\r?\n?", "")` works for you, I will post with explanations.

Comment: @KenWhite your explanation is incorrect, or your regex is ;-) As it stands what you wrote doesn't match lines that "begin with", rather they match "everywhere". your regex would also match a string like "hello arikato 1.6 mr. roboto"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, go right ahead. FYI it's not a multi-string.

Comment: @Jeroen: Yes. Should have anchored the start and end. `^(\d\.\d|Employees).*$` works, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a multiline string as input. In that string, you want to remove the *lines* that start with `digits`+`.`+`digits` or the lines starting with `Employees`.

You can use a `Regex.Replace` with the following regex:

```
Regex.Replace(str, "(?m)^(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+).*[\r\n]*", "")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV5zF7/3)

The regex matches:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+)` - either a `Employees` or one or more digits followed with `.` and followed with one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or LF characters (thus, it will also match several consecutive empty lines).

The CR and LF are optional so that the pattern could match the last line.

[Demo code](http://ideone.com/hrYb4P):

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "1.0- Back of Place" & vbCrLf & "1.1- Drive-thru" & vbCrLf & "Bob Barker" & vbCrLf & "Employees" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "2.1- Closing" & vbCrLf & "Garret Neal" & vbCrLf & "3.0 - Day" & vbCrLf & "3.1 -Day/Night" & vbCrLf & "Bill Gates" & vbCrLf & "4.1- Training" & vbCrLf & "[etc etc etc]"
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, "(?m)^(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+).*[\r\n]*", ""))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

```
Bob Barker
Garret Neal
Bill Gates
[etc etc etc]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Wiktor!

Comment: I read somewhere `\r` isn't necessarily in the most of times when there is `\n`. I mean using both of them is useless (I'm not sure - but I'm sure it is true in the JS language)

Comment: How would you check for a blank value to your regex? Is it **\s?**

Comment: In Windows, a newline sequence is `\r\n`. In Linux/Unix, it is `\n`. In MacOS, it is `\r`. When I write `\r?\n?` I am sure all of them are matched. Now, when I use `\s`, I match all of these "vertical" whitespace, and all *horizontal* whitespace. I do not want to trim the next line, thus, I am not using `\s`. You can use `\s*` if you do not care about that leading whitespace on the next lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but what about a blank as in theres nothing there but **""**.

Comment: @StealthRT: Do you see now that your question is a bit unclear? Please update the question with the requirements. Or a complete set of test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well I just noticed there were blanks in the results after using the RegEX and not before it :o)

Comment: @StealthRT: Not sure what blanks you mean, see [demo](http://ideone.com/hrYb4P) again - I can see no blanks (no empty lines).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Check the OP for the example now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm guessing with the blank also being checked your *RegEX* would be **(?m)^(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+|\s?).*\r?\n?**

Comment: Did you add an empty line? Or a line with a space in it? Well, there are 2 ways now (since I do not have the data): 1) `(?m)^(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+).*[\r\n]*` (as in the [updated demo](http://ideone.com/hrYb4P)), 2) [`(?m)^(?:Employees|\d+\.\d+).*\s*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fm)%5e(%3f%3aEmployees%7c%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b).*%5cs*&i=1.0-+Back+of+Place%0d%0a1.1-+Drive-thru%0d%0aBob+Barker%0d%0aEmployees%0d%0a%0d%0a2.1-+Closing++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%0d%0aGarret+Neal%0d%0a3.0+-+Day%0d%0a3.1+-Day%2fNight%0d%0aBill+Gates%0d%0a4.1-+Training%0d%0a%5betc+etc+etc%5d&r=).

Comment: Can there be empty lines with normal spaces/tabs in between? I will make a final answer update after your feedback.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew from what I am seeing in the output its just an empty line.

Comment: Good, updated. If you ever need to differentiate between spaces and linebreaks, use `\p{Zs}` to match horizontal whitespace and `[\s-[\p{Zs}]]` to match the vertical whitespace.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually the value it seems to be for the empty line is **{}**